# TextClock in AppWidget not responding to any function calls

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on an information widget for the LG V20/V10, to run in the second screen (very easy to add one: just set your category to 36864/0x9000). Currently, I have a battery view and a TextClock in the RemoteViews layout:

```
<!--info_widget.xml-->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="1040px"
    android:layout_height="160px">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/battery"
        layout="@layout/battery_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        layout="@layout/clock_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!--battery_view.xml-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="160px"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/battery_view"
        android:layout_width="70px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:tint="#fff"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_battery_alert_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/battery_percent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="40px" />
</LinearLayout>

<!--clock_view.xml-->

<TextClock xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="64px"
    android:id="@+id/clock_view"/>
```

In my code, I have these functions, which get called from `onUpdate()` for every widget ID (in Kotlin):

```
private fun updateBattery(views: RemoteViews) {
    val level = mBatteryManager?.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY)
    val charging = mBatteryManager?.isCharging

    mBatteryState.updateState(level as Int, charging as Boolean)

    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.battery_view, mBatteryState.imageResource)

    var color = mPrefs?.getInt("battery_color", Color.WHITE)
    var showPercent = mPrefs?.getBoolean("show_percent", true)

    if (color == null) color = Color.WHITE
    if (showPercent == null) showPercent = true

    views.setInt(R.id.battery_view, "setColorFilter", color)
    views.setTextColor(R.id.battery_percent, color)

    if (showPercent) {
        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.battery_percent, View.VISIBLE)
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.battery_percent, mBatteryState.percent.toString() + "%")
    } else {
        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.battery_percent, View.GONE)
    }
}

private fun updateClock(views: RemoteViews) {
    var hour_24 = mPrefs?.getBoolean("24_hour", false)
    var amPm = mPrefs?.getBoolean("am_pm", true)
    var showDate = mPrefs?.getBoolean("show_date", false)
    var color = mPrefs?.getInt("clock_color", Color.WHITE)

    if (hour_24 == null) hour_24 = false
    if (amPm == null) amPm = true
    if (showDate == null) showDate = false
    if (color == null) color = Color.WHITE

    val format: CharSequence = if (showDate) "EE, d " else {""} +  if (hour_24) "k" else {"h"} + ":mm" + if (amPm) " a" else {""}

    views.setCharSequence(R.id.clock_view, "setFormat12Hour", format)
    views.setCharSequence(R.id.clock_view, "setFormat24Hour", format)

    views.setTextColor(R.id.clock_view, color)
}
```

I have a service that gets started, to listen for preference changes and receive broadcast intents, which calls the widget's `onUpdate()` whenever something happens.

Everything works fine in the battery function: I can use the configuration activity to change the tint color and whether or not the percentage is shown, and the changes take place immediately. For whatever, reason, though, the functions in the clock function don't seem to do a thing.

When the view is inflated, and I have a color already set to tint it, it's still white. If I change the format, nothing happens. It's almost as if the TextClock functions aren't actually being called.

I even checked the AOSP source, and it looks like these methods should be allowed from a RemoteViews object: [setFormat12Hour(CharSequence charSequence)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/TextClock.java#307)

What'd I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out, and I honestly have no idea why it's like this. I noticed that when I added another widget to the info screen, it, too, was not responding to changes. So I looked at the differences between the two broken views and the one working view (the battery).

I found that the battery view is enclosed in a LinearLayout, and wouldn't you know it, enclosing the TextClock and the new widget (and ImageView) in dummy LinearLayouts fixed the issue:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextClock
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textSize="64px"
        android:id="@+id/textClock" />

</LinearLayout>
```